# Wireguard VPN, can handshake but can't ping nor ssh

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I'm building a VPN network for remote assistance and data-collection, so I've made up wireguard central server (the only peer with public and static EndPoint) and 4 clients with the same config (excluded their own IPs) in different locations for test.

3 of 4 clients acts as they are supposed to, but 1 of them has a strange behaviour:

- at the begging it handshakes with the server (I can se the data transfer with `wg` command in both peers), but no ping nor ssh works.
- trying with netcat, for UDP connection to the server, works.
- tried to change the listen port on this peer with values of 6000, 60000, 51820 with no effects.
- the next day, without any other change, the peer was working, ping, ssh and everything was working. But after a reboot of the device the situation turns back at beginning.

Notes:

- If I switch the internet connection of the peer from the cabled one to a wifi made with cellular hotspot the peer works as expected.

And here are my questions:

- What can cause this behaviour?
- How can I further investigate?
- How can I solve it?

Thanks